# Refusal of UK visa

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

I had applied for UK sports visa. I have done admission in camp there for about 7 week camp. My visa got refused. It stated that your personal circumstances should be stated but I am a student and thy said that your parents account there is a big amount of money and I showed some property documents which were in Dubai. They said that they alone Is not sufficient. I am applying again my camp is approaching soon please guide me.

Comment: English tip: It's not necessary to address your reader as "sir".  To male readers, it will seem overly formal, and to female readers it will just seem weird.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include a copy of the part of your refusal letter that explains the reasons for the refusal.

Comment: We can't give an authoritative answer without seeing the grounds for your refusal.  Please edit your question to include the text from your refusal notice.  Close voting as 'unclear'